# splitting of dynamic text in a textbox c#

Tags: c#, substring

> User will enter his details in a single textbox like the following
>
> INPUT in a textbox
>
> S. No.    Name    Age     Gender  Concession  Status  Coach   Seat / Berth / WL No
>
> Current Status  Coach   Seat / Berth / WL No    ID Type / ID No.
>
> 1  AYAN PAL    40  Male        CNF S7  49 (LB) CNF S7  49 (LB)

CS CODE

```
            int indexof1 = strMain.IndexOf("1   ");
            int indexof40 = strMain.IndexOf("40 ");
            int indexofstts = strMain.IndexOf("Male     ");
            int effectiveindexof1 = indexof1 + "1   ".Length;
            int effectiveindexof40 = indexof40 + "40    ".Length;
            string pname = strMain.Substring(effectiveindexof1,indexof40-effectiveindexof1);
```

I use substring but it won't help here because all the information provided by user will be dynamic

Comment: I think This is a bad approach to do this. Why not a `.CSV` for input

Comment: What about string.Split() method?

Comment: My client want to do things more easily he just want to copy paste and make my work more difficult any idea about this?

Comment: @JiříVrbas i don't have much idea about how string split work

Comment: for every record there isalways space?

Comment: there is a space and sometimes tab  for every records

Comment: @AngelPriyanka look at my answer

Comment: Why you doesn't do it like    1,AYAN PAL,40,Male, and so on.. split by **","** so that it is easily separatable through split function

Comment: because the user don't want to waste his time on putting coma(,) everywhere @user6002727

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split it like this

```
var input = "1 AYAN PAL 40 Male CNF S7 49 (LB) CNF S7 49 (LB)";
var fields = input.Split(' ');
```

And then just access the each element like this

```
string id = fields[0];
string name = fields[1];
.....
```

**Edit**: diferent count of word

```
        var fullName = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        int number = 0;
        var id = fields[i++];
        while (!int.TryParse(fields[i], out number))
        {
            fullName += fields[i++] + " ";
        }
        fullName = fullName.TrimEnd();
        var age = fields[i++];
        var gender = fields[i++];
        ............
```

Comment: what if he enters the name like priyanka shinde vaibhav what will happen then?

Comment: Than it will crash, this solution will work just for exactly same input, if there will be more elements it doesnt work. You can try testing if fields[i] in for loop is integer, where you know that between ID and Age is name.

Comment: it won't help me much i tried that maybe regex will help me for getting the name

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this will work for name with diferent count of word